# multiple queries in iReport's Report Query Dialog Box

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to make following kind of report using ireport:

```
Total Items: TOTAL_NO_OF_ITEMS
Damaged Items: NO_OF_DAMAGED_ITEMS              
Non Damaged Items: NO_OF_NON_DAMAGED_ITEMS
```

Table structure is:

```
Items{
item id int PK,
item_status varchar  <!--having values as 'damaged' or 'non-damaged')-->
}
```

In **iReport's Report Query Dialog box** I can give query:

```
select count(*) item_counts , item_status status  from Items group by item_status;
```

that will generate

```
Damaged Items: NO_OF_DAMAGED_ITEMS              
Non Damaged Items: NO_OF_NON_DAMAGED_ITEMS
```

BUT for the line in report:

```
Total Items: TOTAL_NO_OF_ITEMS
```

i have to run one more query :

```
select count(*) total_items from items
```

So i want to ask how to can i give more than one queries for a single jrxml file using ireport in Report Dialog Box?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you talking about JasperReport's iReport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for multiple queries for this type of problem. You could do all of the processing in the database if you want:

```
select count(*) as item_counts, item_status as status from Items group by item_status
union all
select count(*) as item_counts, 'all items' as status from Items
```

Or you could do no processing in the database:

```
select * from Items
order by item_status
```

Then in the report create 3 variables to calculate your 3 desired values.

And of course you could use a hybrid. Keep your current query unmodified, and add a variable that sums up the damaged and undamaged items to get the total.

Comment: Thanks! i used third option. By the way ur article on chart customizers (http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/ ) is very helpful.